# how to fix not found 404 in laravel 5.2 validation?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, url, controller

i try to lean laravel and i want to learn validations so i create this blade (create.blade.php)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<form method="POST" action="/posts">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
@endsection
```

and this is the layouts.app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
    @yield('footer')
</body>
</html>
```

and this is for the route

```
Route::resource('/posts', 'PostController');
```

and this is for the controller

```
 public function create()
    {
        //
      // 
      return view('posts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    return $request->all();
    }
```

and when i type on the input form i expect to see what i typed but i keep getting Not found errors!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts">
```

into this

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.store') }}">
```

*Clear configuration cache: If you made any changes to the routes or configuration files, run the following command to clear the configuration cache:*

```
php artisan config:clear
```